# Visual Studio - C++ Error found but won't display

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I am working on an assignment and when I went to build it I receive an error. However, Visual Studio won't tell me what the build error is. It pops up a window and says "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"
Can anyone take a look and let me know if it's something in the code?
Please note: the assignment isnt complete yet, the error is driving me nuts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

void ExitPgm();

int main() {

    int studID, quizGrade, i;
    fstream File;

    cout << "Enter a 0 for no students \n";
    cout << "Enter student ID: \n";
    cin >> studID;
    cout << endl;

    File.open("Quizzes.txt");

    while (studID != 0)
    {   
        File << studID << "\t";

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter quiz grade: ";
            cin >> quizGrade;
            if (quizGrade < 0 || quizGrade > 100)
            {
                cout << "Invalid quiz grade\n";
                ExitPgm();
            }
            File << quizGrade << "\t";
        }
        File << "\n";
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter a 0 for no more students or enter student ID\n";
        cin >> studID;
    }
    File.close();

    File.open("Quizzes.txt");
    File >> studID;
    File >> quizGrade;
    cout << studID << " " << quizGrade << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ExitPgm()
{
    cout << "Have a nice day! \n";
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just 'build' (likely F7)  and do not 'build and run' (likely F5) and watch  the error list and/or the build output

Comment: Look at the "Build" tab or window.  Usually it's at the bottom under the source code window.

Comment: BTW, your `ExitPgm` function doesn't exit the program, it displays text, pauses and returns.  Your program, then continues.  You will need a return in the `main` function to exit the program.

Comment: Look in the output window.  If it is not showing, you can find it under the View menu option.

Comment: Ok, so I shut down my computer to run an errand. Came back and started up Visual Studio. I did the "Build" and no errors came up. Then I pressed the "(Play button) Local Windows Debugger" and it ran fine. I made no changes to the code. Hopefully this issue doesn't appear again. Thanks for your help!